# Java client / server thread null pointer exception when quickly communicating messages

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, javafx

I'm using JavaFX to create a simple messenger client.  The classes in question are:

MainMenuController.class: this class handles JavaFX ui logic such as printing chat messages to text area

Server.class: controls server socket and in/out logic

Client.class: controls client socket and in/out logic

I'm able to run the application perfectly on local host, except my program throws a nullpointerexception when I try to send messages too quickly.  I'll past the relevant code, and then I'll explain what I've tried to solve this bug.

MainMenuController.java (exception traced to this function)

```
public static void printMessage(String sender, String msg) {
    //msgHistory is a textArea
    msgHistory.appendText(sender + ": " +msg + "\n");
}
```

Server.java

```
try {
    servSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);

    MainMenuController.printMessage("Server running on port: "
        + serverPort + ". . .");

    // block till we accept connection request
    clientSocket = servSocket.accept();

    out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        clientSocket.getInputStream()));

    // receive and set friend's alias
    friendName = in.readLine();
    aliasSet = true;

    String input;

    // while connection is present, poll server socket input for new
    // messages
    while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        input = in.readLine();

        if (input == null) {
            break;
        }

        //update status 
        MainMenuController.printMessage(friendName, input);  //Line traced to exception
    }
}
```

Client.java

```
try {   
    socket = new Socket (serverAddr, portNum);

    MainMenuController.printMessage("Connected!");

    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    //send server our alias
    out.println(myName);

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Accept failed.");
}
```

I believe the exception is caused by the client and server trying to write to the textArea in MainMenuController at the same time.  I've experimented with adding a thread.sleep(x) before the server prints to textArea.  I've also implemented a public lock in the MainMenuController class.  In each call to printMessage in both the server and client, I wait until the lock is free before calling the printMessage method (I set the lock before calling printMessage, then free it once the method has returned).  I took this code out to make it more readable.  Neither of these solutions have worked and I'm not sure where to look.

the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGTextHelper$TextAttributes.computeLinePadding(NGTextHelper.java:405)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGTextHelper$TextAttributes.access$200(NGTextHelper.java:292)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGTextHelper.buildTextLines(NGTextHelper.java:2357)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGTextHelper.validateText(NGTextHelper.java:1847)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGTextHelper.getCaretShape(NGTextHelper.java:1435)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.getDecorationShapes(Text.java:1150)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.impl_geomChanged(Text.java:757)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text$1.invalidated(Text.java:214)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:127)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:161)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:67)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.setText(Text.java:188)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextAreaSkin$17.invalidated(TextAreaSkin.java:610)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:359)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:100)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl$TextProperty.fireValueChangedEvent(TextInputControl.java:1034)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl$TextProperty.markInvalid(TextInputControl.java:1038)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl$TextProperty.invalidate(TextInputControl.java:978)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl$TextProperty.access$200(TextInputControl.java:950)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl$1.invalidated(TextInputControl.java:119)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:155)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:100)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextArea$TextAreaContent.insert(TextArea.java:196)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.replaceText(TextInputControl.java:373)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.insertText(TextInputControl.java:308)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.appendText(TextInputControl.java:298)
    at application.MainMenuController.printMessage(MainMenuController.java:96)
    at application.Server.run(Server.java:79)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Edit: This error only occurs with textArea.appendText(string).  No exception is thrown with textArea.setText(string).

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to call JavaFX methods from an arbitrary thread, but only from the JavaFX Application Thread. Wrap your `msgHistory.appendText` in a [Platform.runLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) call.

Comment: This works, thank you!  I have a followup question: I received this error: Cannot refer to a non-final variable msg inside an inner class defined in a different method.  I solved this by creating two temporary, final strings for the sender and msg parameters of printMessage().  Is there a more efficient workaround for this?

Comment: You can directly declare the method parameters as final. I don't think there is a real efficiency gain, but it's less cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't checking `friendName` for null. Any `readLine()` invocation can return null.

NB Sleeping before calling `readLine()` is literally a waste of time. It will block until data is available.

Comment: When the client connects, it sends a message containing the friend alias.  This is set in a field of the Server class before the while loop.  I don't think this is the root of the problem because the exception always happens several messages into the conversation.